# C++ constant temporary lifetime

Tags: c++

Can you please tell me if such code is correct (according to standard):

```
struct array {
    int data[4];
    operator const int*() const { return data; }
};

void function(const int*) { ... }

function(array()); // is array data valid inside function?
```

Thank you

Comment: @Martin yes, I wanted to be sure it is valid rather than lucky compiler coincidence.  I do know about lifetime of objects, but I was not sure about object cast like this

Comment: very wise. As a rule of thumb, you can usually expect that, if something can be checked or enforced at compile time, then it will be. Undefined behaviour usually comes when a runtime check would be needed to prevent it. But, as you say, it's always better to make sure.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. The temporary object is valid until the end of the full expression in which it is created; that is, until after the function call returns.

I don't have my copy of the standard to hand, so I can't give the exact reference; but it's in 12.2 of the [C++0x final draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf).

Answer (score 6):

Yes. Temporaries are valid until the end of the full expression in which they are created. Therefore the nameless array temporary would be valid until the call to `function` returns, and so its `data` member would be as well.